# Having trouble isolating for y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation $x^3(y-1)^2 = 4y^4(x-1)^3$ and I'm trying to isolate for y.

No matter what I do, I keep getting $\frac{y-1}{y^2} = \frac{2(x-1)^{3/2}}{x^{3/2}}$

I have no idea how to isolate for y here.

Answer (score 1):

Try multiplying out by $y^2$ and using the quadratic formula.

Comment: Do you mean $y-1 = \frac{2(x-1)^{3/2}}{x^{3/2}}*y^2$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. It probably won't be a very nice expression but it's what you have

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging, we get $$\left( \frac{2(x-1)^{3/2}}{x^{3/2}} \right) y^2 - y + 1 = 0.$$ Now use the quadratic formula with $a= \frac{2(x-1)^{3/2}}{x^{3/2}}, b = -1$ and $c=1$.